# is it a problem to fire very many queries to a mysql db?

Tags: mysql, performance

think about having a skript where you have some words as input.
now you trie to find matches of each word in a tablecolumn.
i want to count the results for each word, so i think i have to do a query for each word, isn't it?

in a second step i'm having a look at the counts of results and depending on that number i check severl other table columns... so i will have many queries for many words ....

is this a problem?
is there an other way to do such requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your actual query. You might be able to do it in one query but even doing hundreds of queries is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a query which matches either one word or a group of words, and construct a query based on the list of words submitted. This kind of dynamic SQL is actually pretty quick, the biggest bottlenecks will be in your database structure, the number of records present and how well indexed your data is.